# Webpack merges code-splitted chunk into parent chunk

Tags: reactjs, webpack, relay

I am trying to load the data and the react component in parallel but webpack keeps merging the two into to the same parent chunk.
Using webpack 3 and both are using ES modules.

```
// Router.js
import loadable from 'react-loadable';
import { query } from './RouteA';

const routeA = () => import('./RouteA');

render((
  <Router>
    <RelayRoute path="/" query={query} component={loadable({ loader: routeA, loading: () => null })} />
  </Router>
));

// RouteA.js

export const query = graphql`
  query RouteAQuery {
    viewer {
      user {
        details {
          firstName
        }
      }
    }
  } 
`;

export default function RouteA() {
  return <h1>RouteA</h1>;
}
```

Comment: show your config

Comment: `module.exports = {
  entry: './test.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
  }
}`

Comment: It would def be good to see the config here.